# How to capture each cell inside foreach; so, when a cell is empty, it shows an error text

Tags: c#, foreach, ado.net

At the beginning, my problem was how to validate an empty field of a grid, what this event do to validate all cells and how to show the error text when a cell is empty.

So, my new problem is how to capture each cell inside foreach; so, when a cell is empty, it shows an error text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run foreach loop like this. and based on the text you can do whatever you want to

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewId.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GridViewId.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        String cellText = row.Cells[i].Text;
    }
}
```